# C# タスクバーも含む、指定したプログラムが起動中かどうかを調べる方法

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

初歩的な質問です。

指定した実行ファイル(プログラム)が起動中かどうかを調べる方法を探しています。
サイト様などではProcess.GetProcessesByNameなどを使ってということが書かれていますが、
プログラムを最小化してしまうとこれに引っかからなくなってしまいます。

最小化してデスクトップ上では非表示の状態であっても、起動中という情報を取得するにはどのようにすればよいでしょぅか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

最小化してもProcess.GetProcessesByNameで取得することは可能です。ですので、取得できないのであれば何か別の問題と思われます。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。…ただ、特別なことは何もしていません。認識したいのはAccessのなのですが、最少すると取得できませんでした。Office系列だけは何か特別な仕様になっているのでしょうか？